# Importing a wp made site and its mysql database

Tags: wordpress

Hope I am not asking a duplicate question. I am new to wordpress.  I am trying to learn it by importing an already existing e-commerce wp website (with its content and my sql database) in my localhost and then play with it. The closest link i found was this [import](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/importing-a-website-into-wordpress) 
Any help on how to any wp made e-commerce website and how to import it to my local host is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-importer/, it offers very easy data import

Comment: Thanks a lot, how about an e-commerce website I could import and edit. Do you know of any?